# How to make conditional expansion without subshell?

Tags: shell, macros, gnu-make

I wrote following function in GNU Make, that checks whether first argument belongs is found in some list, and expands to second or third argument accordingly:

```
FLAGS := foo bar
use = $(shell { echo $(FLAGS) | grep -qw $(1) ; } && echo $(2) || echo $(3))

all:
»   $(info $(call use, foo, have-foo, no-foo))
»   $(info $(call use, baz, have-baz, no-baz))
```

It behaves as I want:

```
$ make all
have-foo
no-baz
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

- Is there any way to implement same functionality only with GNU Make, 
  without subshell?
- Is there any way to add more syntax sugar at call sites?

I need it work on GNU Make built without Guile support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand but why not this?

```
use = $(if $(filter $1,$(FLAGS)),$2,$3)
```

??

Answer (score 0):

While MadScientists answer may be all you need, it looks like you are doing the configuration management in `make`. While this is IMO the place where it should happen, the heritage has prevented `make` from becoming a full-flegded tool for that purpose. However, there is a library which helps in this case: [The GNUmake Table Toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) lets you select from a table those lines which fulfill certain freely defined condition (read the documentation to `select`).

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

# original definition of the flag table
define FLAG-TABLE
2
foo  have-foo-1
foo  have-foo-2
bar  have-bar-1

endef

# GNUmake even allows to write an addendum to a define:
define FLAG-TABLE +=
bar have-bar-2
foo have-foo-3

endef

# the $1 is where the parameter of the call to MY-SELECTION is placed; the $$1 is 
# where the first column of the table is put before calling `str-eq`
MY-SELECTION = $(call select,2,$(FLAG-TABLE),$$(call str-eq,$$1,$1))

$(info $(FLAG-TABLE))
$(info ------------------)
$(info $(call MY-SELECTION,foo))
$(info ------------------)
$(info $(call MY-SELECTION,bar))
```

Output:

```
$ make
2
foo  have-foo-1
foo  have-foo-2
bar  have-bar-1
 bar have-bar-2
foo have-foo-3

------------------
 have-foo-1 have-foo-2 have-foo-3
------------------
 have-bar-1 have-bar-2
```